# Python cannot find PyAudio

Tags: python, pyaudio

I am planning to do a VA for myself.

I have tried this code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

listener = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print('listening')
    voice = listener.listen(source)
    info = listener.recognize_google(voice)
    print(info)
```

But when I run it in my IDE I am getting this attribute error.

```
import pyaudio
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "D:/Shounak/workspace/Python/email-bot/main.py", line 8, in <module>
   with sr.Microphone() as source:
 File "C:\Users\shoun.PDK_WIN7_LP\.virtualenvs\email-bot\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 79, in __init__
   self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()
 File "C:\Users\shoun.PDK_WIN7_LP\.virtualenvs\email-bot\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 110, in get_pyaudio
   raise AttributeError("Could not find PyAudio; check installation")
AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation
```

I have installed PyAudio in my terminal, but I am still getting this error.

Comment: in my experience "I installed it in a terminal" and "not found in my IDE" is almost always that you have 2 separate python installations. Call `sys.executable` to get the location of the running python executable from both your IDE and the terminal to confirm.

Comment: I am new to python , can you tell how to execute sys.executable?

Comment: from an interactive prompt: call `import sys` then call `sys.executable` it should print the file path to an executable file. In windows that means an "exe" file typically. OSX, and linux systems typically don't have a file extension for executable files

Comment: The executable paths are different in my pycharm terminal and my cmd.

Comment: having 2 different python installations isn't a bad thing per-se, but it does make things more confusing. If you have a mac or linux machine, there's a built-in system python that's needed for the OS, and can't be deleted. If you're on windows, I would just get rid of the one pycharm isn't using unless you have another good reason to keep it. What OS do you have?

Comment: I am on windows. Actually Pycharm had made a virtual environment and is running by that path.

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003445839-Stop-setting-up-projects-as-virtual-environments-in-PyCharm

Comment: Pycharm is a very advanced IDE with lots of great features, but sometimes I recommend to new players to use just notepad++ and cmd for the sake of learning how things work under the hood. Once you understand it better, you'll be able to take better advantage of the tools a powerful IDE can provide, and won't be caught off-gaurd by the things it does in the background.

Comment: What is "VA"? Virtual assistant? Voice actress? Voice actor? Voice artist? Do you mean "AV"? Audiovisual? Or something else? Please respond by [editing (changing) your question](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14995715/incognitoman), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: "VA" is probably voice assistant or [virtual assistant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_assistant) (like [Cortana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cortana), [Google Assistant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Assistant), [Alexa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Alexa), and [Siri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siri)).

Answer (score 1):

Is your IDE using a Python virtual environment? If so, make sure PyAudio is installed in the virtual environment, not in the global Python interpreter.

Comment: you should elaborate a bit on this. It is the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your system is missing some dependencies.

First try executing the below command.

```
pip install pipwin
```

then

```
pipwin install PyAudio
```

**Or**

You can try below the version

```
pip install PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl
```

Visit [PyAudio](https://pypi.org/project/PyAudio/). You can download it manually.

Answer (score 0):

In the IDE command prompt you are using, install PyAudio

```
pip install PyAudio
```

Comment: Why does it have to be an IDE command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the version of PyAudio installed is compatible with the version of Python you have.

Comment: It is compactible, yes

Comment: I have not installed it in the venv so, it is happening I guess as vrevolver told